# Request full MediaDeviceInfo without audio/video capture

Tags: javascript, audio, html5-audio, getusermedia, mediadevices

I'm using the MediaDevices API to get a list of audio output devices:

```
const outputDevices = (
  await navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()
).filter(device => device.kind === 'audiooutput');
```

This works, but `label` is blank.

I know that if I use `getUserMedia()` to request an audio or video stream, that I can then re-enumerate devices and get their labels.  Is there any way to get permission to view the devices *without* `getUserMedia()`?  I want to set the sink ID of audio output and have no reason to use capture devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [known limitation](https://github.com/w3c/mediacapture-output/issues/83) of the Audio Output Devices API unfortunately - the discussion on the github issue point towards possible solutions, but no clear decision has been made yet.

Answer (score 0):

To get this information, I've had to do a simple `getUserMedia ({audio: true})` operation first. It's no problem to delete the tracks in the stream, then drop the stream, when you're done enumerating.

It's going to demand user permission. Why?  Because malicious parties could possibly use your device enumeration data to fingerprint your browser and help track you.